# Spring JPA repository, select data which contains all elements from param list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have spring JPA Repository Interface:

```
public interface ElementLogRepository extends JpaRepository<ElementLog, String>
```

There is Query:

```
@Query("SELECT pl.element.id FROM ElementLog pl WHERE pl.tags IN :tags)")
public List<ElementLog> findLatestElementLogsByTags(@Param("tags") List<Tag> tags);
```

When I call method `findLatestElementLogsByTags` I receive all `ElementLog` which contains any tag from `List<Tag> tags`.

How can I modify query to get all `ElementLog` which contains all tags from `List<Tag> tags` ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So basically instead of list of `ElementLog` with single tag each, you want single `ElementLog` with list of all tags?

Answer (score 1):

First,I think the ElementLog And Tag is related with OneToMany.

```
SELECT log FROM ElementLog log WHERE log.id IN (
     SELECT DISTINCT pl.id FROM ElementLog pl join pl.tags as t where t in :tags group by pl.id having count(pl.id) == :tags.size()
)
```

my think is compare with match size,the hql should be correct, I did not actually run over.